# Date.now().toISOString() throwing error "not a function"

Tags: node.js

I am running Node v6.4.0 on Windows 10.  In one of my Javascript files I am trying to get an ISO date string from the Date object:

```
let timestamp = Date.now().toISOString();
```

This throws:
Date.now(...).toISOString is not a function

Looking through stackoverflow this should work...possible bug in Node?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`Date.now()` returns a number which represents the number of milliseconds elapsed since the UNIX epoch. The `toISOString` method cannot be called on a number, but only on a `Date` object, like this:

```
var now = new Date();
var isoString = now.toISOString();
```

Or in one single line:

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was misusing Date.now() as stated.

Comment: Bug in developer :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Like the OP I was trying to spare an extra object by using Date.now().toISOString() but thinking back it doesn't make sense whatsoever, I should have immediately spotted the difference between a 'Date object' and a 'number' :-) Alas, tired amateur developer here...

Comment: ... just a note to the OP, this has nothing to do with Node.js or Windows 10!

Comment: Spare the extra object anyway: `new Date().toISOString()`

Answer (score -2):

If anybody wonder if you can convert excisting date.Now() timestamp to an actual date: yes, you can. Just:

```
new Date(put your timestamp here).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
```

and you will get date in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31735258)