# ERROR TypeError: something.toISOString is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I'm working on an angular application where I run into a problem. The problem is in this function:

```
dayManipulate(object) {

    var startTime = new Date(object.date.toISOString());
    let localDate = new Date().toLocaleString();
    console.log("Diff: ", (startTime.getTimezoneOffset() * -1) / 60);
    console.log("local: ", localDate);
    startTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + (startTime.getTimezoneOffset() * -60000));
    let dateObj = object.date;

    let day = dateObj.getDate().toString();
    day = +day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
    let month = (dateObj.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    month = +month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
    let year = dateObj.getFullYear();
    let formattedDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    object.date = formattedDate;
    return object;
  }
```

The function is for to fix an error in angular datepicker where the chosen date (e.g. 2020-02-12) returns a day before, but unfortunately I run into the typeError for `toISOString` is not a function because it returns a string and can't handle Date, I tried to fix it but run into other not a function errors. Is there a solution to fix this somehow? or I have to write a new function to fix the datePicker's error.

Comment: Can you please share how the `object` looks like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date.now().toISOString() throwing error "not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217275/date-now-toisostring-throwing-error-not-a-function)

Comment: What Umair has asked. Also check if your string is compatible with [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). If not, you need to parse the string manually (eg. with regex) before using it with `new Date(string)`.

Comment: my date object is : '2020-02-12'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your date object like this it will solve your problem

> object={date:'2019-02-21'}

```
  dayManipulate(object) {

    var startTime = new Date(new Date(object.date).toISOString());
    let localDate = new Date().toLocaleString();
    console.log("Diff: ", (startTime.getTimezoneOffset() * -1) / 60);
    console.log("local: ", localDate);
    startTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + (startTime.getTimezoneOffset() * -60000));
    let dateObj = new Date(object.date);

    let day = dateObj.getDate().toString();
    console.log(day)
    day = +day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
    let month = (dateObj.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    month = +month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
    let year = dateObj.getFullYear();
    let formattedDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    object.date = formattedDate;
    console.log(object.date)
    return object;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is I get this error then: ```ERROR TypeError: dateObj.getDate is not a function```

Answer (score 3):

Give the following a go...

```
var startTime = new Date(object.date).toISOString();
```

It looks like object.date is a string, so you can't call `.toIsoString()` on it.
You must first convert it to a date object.

Based on your comments, do something like this.

```
var startDate = new Date(object.date);
var startDateIso = startDate.toIsoString();
var startTime = startDate.getTime();
```

Comment: yes i tried this but then ```getTime()``` and ```getTimezoneOffset()``` won't work with an error that these functions doesn't exist on type string

Comment: You need to call those functions on the date object. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

var startTime = new Date(object.date.toISOString());

Problem in the above code is that toISOString() only works on Date objects.
instead use:

var startTime = new Date(object.date).toISOString();