# Creating a "date modified" value in React --Edit: updated to working code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time

I need to grab the date/time the value is modified so I can update it in state, then push it through context to an addNote function in App.js. One example from the json server is "2019-01-03T00:00:00.000Z" So I need the date and time to match this format.

```
export class AddNote extends Component {
    state = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        modified: '', 
        folderId: '',
        content: ''
    }

    static contextType = Context;

    handleChange = (e) => {
     const { modified } = e.target.dataset.modified; <---------
        this.setState({
            id: e.target.id, 
            name: e.target.value, 
            modified: {modified}, 
            folderId: e.target.dataset.folderId
        })
    }
```

```
render() {
        const id = uuidv4();
        const folderId = uuidv4();
        const date = new Date() <-------------------
        const isoString = date.toISOString(); <-------------

        return (
            <div>
                <form 
                    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                    className='AddNoteForm'
                >
                    <h2>Add Note</h2>
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        id={id}
                        value={this.state.name}
                        data-folderId={folderId}
                        data-modified={isoString} <------------
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
```

Comment: Where is your DateTime that you want to match to the one returned from the server? is it the `this.state.modified` ?

Comment: That's the other half of the issue I've just realized. I can convert it as answered below, but first I need to grab the value to start with

Comment: Okay, that's actually what I'm after... the value.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to create it WITHOUT making a field for the user to manually input the date?

Comment: That's easy. You just create a `new Date()` and this will return the current Date and Time.  If a user is inputing some data, just wait until they submit and when you bind the model you create an extra-field for the date and create an instance of `Date` using `new Date()`. and then you can use that `(new Date()).toISOString()` to conver it. But obviously you would've stored it into a variable

Comment: I updated the code to what I've tried, but I'm getting "e.target.modified is undefined"

Comment: Ok please check my answer. I have suggested some few fixes on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to really Note:

`const { modified } = e.target.modified.toISOString() <-----"e.target.modified is undefined"` This is because you didn't bind your `handleChange()` function in your `constructor()`. So bind it.

```
constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

If you didn't set the `.bind()` for that `handleChange` your function won't work properly. because it's not binding to anything. Learn more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). I am pretty sure that after doing this, everything should work. If not, try the following recommendations.

---

Some Information from [React](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html)

**Should I Keep Data in Custom Attributes?**

*No. We don’t encourage you to keep data in DOM attributes. Even if you have to, data- attributes are probably a better approach, but in most cases data should be kept in React component state or external stores.*

---

As you have set your attribute, try to actually inspect the rendered element to see if that attribute is rendered. I would advise saving data on `data-attribute`, which you can further learn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285856/how-do-i-dynamically-set-html5-data-attributes-using-react) how to use `data-attr` with react.

A Quick example:

```
<input 
    type="text"
    id={id}
    value={this.state.name}
    data-folderId={folderId} // add data-
    data-modified={date} <------------ //add data-
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Build your code and inspect element to actually check if the attributes are rendered with those values. This is to just verify that the approach is working. Then you can retrieve those attribute.

Comment: Got it working! It was a combination of a few things, apparently you have to convert the date first before passing it. The dat- and dataset method solved the problem with not recognizing "this.modified". I updated the OP to represent the working code.

Comment: I am not sure why the conversion was necessary prior to assigning the value because it's stored as a string on the attribute so it won't make a difference. But I am Glad and happy that you found your solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217275/date-now-toisostring-throwing-error-not-a-function (apparently it's a bug). But yes, everything is working now. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an ISO string representing a datetime object in vanilla JS. Once you have the datetime object, you can call the below to correctly output the above.

```
const event = new Date('05 October 2011 14:48 UTC');
console.log(event.toString());
// expected output: Wed Oct 05 2011 16:48:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
// (note: your timezone may vary)

console.log(event.toISOString());
// expected output: 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z
```

The link to Mozilla docs where this is describe is below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

One thing to note when considering timestamps for events, logging, metrics or really anything. Make a decision early on the format you will be saving the timestamp data in and stick to it, which after trial and error ISO8601 compliant timestamps that include as much information about offset as possible, are a good place to start. Otherwise the consistency of timezone management will become an issue later.